# Converting For Loop to a While Loop (List)

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have to convert:

```
public void listFunction(ArrayList<String>list)
{
   for (String listItem: list){
      System.out.println(listItem);
   }
}
```

This does not look like the for loops I have converted before. How do I do this?

Comment: please edit your question to make it easier to read (add spaces in the method header for example), also add what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this

```
    int j = 0;
    while (list.size() > j) {
        System.out.println(list.get(j));
        j++;
    }
```